# Android Activity create and start

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently writting an app for Android. I'm trying to figure out the best place to catch on intent when the activity is created for the first time.

```
public class DisplayAct extends Activity {

    private Intent mNewIntent;
    private ViewFinderFragment mViewFinderFrag;
    public boolean toot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);    

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent != null) {
                String action = intent.getAction();         
            }
     }
```

This is how I get the intent.

I was wondering if grabbing the intent at oncreate is good or it's better to add onStart and add this action inside in term of design perspective.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you app is open, handle it with onNewIntent. If you app is closed, you wanna use your Bundle that comes with your Intent.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.getString(MY_ACTION)) {
        // Do something
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I set this action as a String to the Intent's Bundle. I performed it with the code below:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(MainActivity.MY_ACTION, "MY_ACTION");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: @Tea but how to get intent.getAction associated ?

Comment: @Tea but the action is supposed to be  in intent.getAction

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete answer. In my case, besides the Intent's action, I set this action (String) to the Intent's Bundle. So in onCreate you get this Bundle and check if you have an action to perform. I'll provide more code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks I got the point. I'm newbie... how can I find who start the onCreate ? in order to allow me to add bundle

Comment: Yourself. Whenever you send an Intent to your MainActivity you can attach a bundle, then you handle it the way I showed you